# filefiles node and comment in one view

Tags: files

I have a content type called "Document" where i have a "file" field so i can upload files. I also have comments enable where another users can add a comment and also upload more files.

Whats i would like to do is have a table of all uploaded file in a single table at the bottom of the node.

In Views i am unable to get files upload from the node and comments in one views. Can anyone help with this?

using Drupal 7

Thanks

Comment: How did you set up file attachments with comments?

Answer (score 0):

On the view that you have the files upload, under Advanced, add a relationship of comments of the node, then add Comment:Comment as a field.

Comment: I've try the above Can this been done in file view? showing all files attract to the node and comment

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use [File Entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, which provides all the functionality you need.

> File entity provides interfaces for managing files. It also extends the core file entity, allowing files to be fieldable, grouped into types, viewed (using display modes) and formatted using field formatters. File entity integrates with a number of modules, exposing files to Views, Entity API, Token and more.